# Syntax error while trying to generate a 2048bit long prime number

Tags: bash, syntax-error, bc, xxd

I'm trying to generate a 2048 bit long prime number, this is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

generate_random() {
    hex=$(head -c 256 /dev/urandom | xxd -p)
    bc <<< "ibase=16; $hex"
}

p=$(generate_random)

echo "$p"
```

While running the script I get `(standard_in) 1: syntax error` followed by random zeroes.

Anyone knows what is causing this error and how can I fix it? I've tried with `bash -x`, but it doesn't add any useful information.

Comment: What should `$hex` contain and what should `bc` output?

Comment: @Cyrus `$hex` contains a random number generated by `/dev/urandom` in hex format. `bc` convert the hex string stored in `$hex` to a decimal number

Comment: Hint: you can simplify the problem by doing a `bc <<< "ibase=16; 868f"`, which would also show this error. If you would run this with -x turned on, you would see how the input to `bc` actually looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `bc` understands only upper-case letters as hex digits (at least by default). Second, you have separators in your `xxd` output, so you generate multiple numbers with `bc` later.

This should work:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

generate_random() {
    hex=$(head -c 256 /dev/urandom | xxd -p -u | tr -d '\n')
    bc <<< "ibase=16; $hex"
}

p=$(generate_random)
echo "$p"
```

`-u` flag to `xxd` instructs it to output upper-case letters as digits, and `tr` removes separators.

Example output:

```
84404284040092528807148386035025161100484110236893077703095592941720\
00537078513504880246726730474236368181068985417211434943913923235822\
01284401417146606673073772989889733010524123703686975444423088406509\
44767677616371794606797386146855833950295071249000795855185540560405\
62673903614333076371092344026999031152809898928396395497832309795471\
93897215963003601022703133486344387720277877558264139632520964120681\
97764906669023878701319760947789227343517474218584987497204300184084\
62846775760153647010072072799120566180042021620262646969602253704108\
06274157727080642084167983313757899766696995668747042179553171962777\
5716
```

To remove newline separators and backslashes, you can do

```bash
p_joined=$(echo "$p" | sed -z 's=\\\n==g')
echo "$p_joined"
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way might be

```
printf -v hex '%s' $(od -v -An -N256 -x /dev/urandom)
read dec < <(bc <<< "ibase=16; ${hex^^}")
echo $dec
```